# How to prevent focusing of QSlider when touch scrolling with QScroller?

Tags: qt, qt5, qslider, qabstractslider

I have a QScrollArea with `QScroller::grabGesture(wgt, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);`. Inside it, I have multiple widgets. I'm trying to make it work in such a way so that people can scroll using touch gestures without worrying about accidentally focusing and changing values of the elements inside.

I am unable to achieve this with QSlider. I have even tried overloading `QSlider::event` and ignoring everything in it abd the slider is still capturing the events somehow and it does not scroll.

I find it even weirder that the QDoubleSpinbox on the left does not have these issues and the drag touch event is correctly ignored until you click on the item. Both QDoubleSpinBox and QSlider have focus policy set to StrongFocus.

Can someone help me with this?

[image]